# What is splice.call?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

The kendoui has `splice.call(oldValues, i, 1);` code.

What is mean?

It not worked in IE8.

If I understand it should remove one item after **i** in oldValues ?

```
if (!found) {
    remove.push(old);
    splice.call(oldValues, i, 1);
    removeIndex = i;
} else {
    i += 1;
}
```

Comment: What is *oldValues*? If it's a host object (e.g. an HTML Collection or NodeList) then you can't use it as *this* in a built–in function with IE 8 or lower. From the spec: "The splice function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object … Whether the splice function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent." [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12).

Answer (score 2):

`splice.call(oldValues, i, 1)` will run the splice function on the oldValues array, as if it was a method of an object. Think of it as `oldValues.splice(i, 1)`.

splice() itself removes and adds elements from/to an array, in this case, it will remove `1` element from the array `oldValues` at position `i`

Comment: Probably worth noting that somewhere in the code will be the line `var splice = Array.prototype.splice;`.

Comment: Yes. `var splice = Array.prototype.splice;` and what is means ? why it is not work?

Comment: var splice = Array.prototype.splice means that you save the Array method splice() to the object splice, which will allow you to rebind it to oldValues with splice.call(oldValues, pos, length, ...)

Comment: @AronCederholm—I think what you meant to say is that `var splice = Array.prototype.splice` assigns a reference to the *Array.splice* method to the variable *splice* so that there is less to type later.

Comment: @RobG Yes, you are correct. That is exactly what I meant. Indeed, you don't copy the Array.splice method to a object, as I (a little clumsily) indicated, but you assign a reference to a variable. Thanks!